# Which, if any, EU28 countries have expressed opposition to the creation of a European Security Council?

Tags: europe, geopolitics, national-security

There has been some talk about setting up a *European Security Council* to make collective foreign policy decision more swiftly. For example, [an article on the German Institute for International and Security Affairs website](https://www.swp-berlin.org/10.18449/2019C02/) introduces the concept as follows:

> A European Security Council (ESC) would – so the German government has suggested – make the European Union (EU) better prepared for making decisions about inter­national politics and thus better able to act. It believes that if the EU and its member states do not manage to take and implement coherent decisions more quickly, their ability to (further) enforce European rules and strengthen multilateral formats will be weakened. The EU-27’s diplomatic, financial and military resources should there­fore be supplemented by a format for more effective intergovernmental cooperation. However, this idea can only take shape if the German government can demonstrate the added value of such a body, and if it shows more willingness itself to shape for­eign policy within the EU framework.

Since then, [an article on the Centre for European Reform website](https://www.cer.eu/in-the-press/european-security-council-good-idea) talked about French support for the idea:

> In an effort to tackle this frailty, France and Germany have proposed setting up a ‘European Security Council’ (ESC). While the idea of an ESC has been around for years, it was recently revitalised by French President Emmanuel Macron, and has also been endorsed by German foreign minister Heiko Maas and other senior German politicians. France and Germany have not yet put forward a detailed blueprint for the ESC, but it appears it would have a dual purpose. First, allowing close consultation and coordination with the UK after Brexit, keeping London plugged into European decision-making. Second, making Europe a more agile and forceful player in foreign and security policy.

Has any EU28 country expressed opposition to the formation of such a council?

---

I specifically used the EU28 reference because the idea of the ESC would be that the UK is included in these foreign policy decisions as well. As an [article in Carnegie Europe](https://carnegieeurope.eu/strategiceurope/80869) wrote:

> Third, an ESC could provide a new pan-European architecture to keep the UK connected with the European foreign policy orbit. This might mitigate the perceived post-Brexit risk of weakened European global influence if London aligned more with the outlook of U.S. President Donald Trump. An ESC would bring all Europe’s main foreign and security powers—whether inside or outside the EU—together.

As I understand it, the ESC would not necessarily be linked to the European Union. My using the EU28 term is just to have a clear set of countries that are probably expected to participate in one way or another with the ESC if the idea ever comes to fruition.

Comment: I don't have an answer, just to mention that France has been pushing for stronger military cooperation at the European level for some time. But from the French point of view it's also a matter of sharing the cost of military operations abroad. Probably some countries don't want to commit to such a goal, so I could imagine that there are disagreements about the scope and cost of the European security strategy in general.